# Updating SQL database using jQuery Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

So i am trying to use ajax to update a value in my sql database by grabbing the link that was clicked and finding that link in the database. I'm not sure why it isn't working :\

```
$('.visit').click( function() {
var thisLink = $(this).attr('href'); 
$.post("visit.php", { link: thisLink});
});

<?php
$link = $_POST['link'];
mysql_query("UPDATE items SET visited = 1 WHERE link = $link");
include("print.php");
?>
```

Comment: Also take a look at the 'bind-param' method. You currently have a situation where someone could post to the following url and cause issues. yoursite.com/visit.php?link='data;DROP TABLE [items]'

Comment: @rcravens right I understand. How would I modify this code using that?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the SQL injection use something like the following (typed from memory...double check).

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('connection string', 'username', 'password');

    $query = "UPDATE items SET visited=1 WHERE link=:link";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':link' => $link));
?>
```

Bob

Comment: adding PDO support is php5 (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0, PECL pdo >= 0.1.0) or PECL

Comment: @kjy112 good point. Thanks for the example using mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('.visit').click( function() {
         var thisLink = $(this).attr('href'); 
         $.post("visit.php", { link: thisLink});
    });

    <?php
         $link = $_POST['link'];
         mysql_query("UPDATE items SET visited = '1' WHERE link = '".mysql_real_escape_string($link)."'");
         include("print.php");
    ?>
```

use single quote around SET and WHERE params.  Also, mysql_escape_real_string inputs into database for SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
  $link = $_POST['link']; 
  mysql_query("UPDATE items SET visited = 1 WHERE link = '$link'"); 
  include("print.php"); // what print.php does ?
 ?>
```

put quotes around $link

compare $link with value in database field - it need to be exaclly match

Comment: this is the only problem I can see also

Comment: hmm yeah that didn't seem to work. I am checking the database and it isn't getting updated. My table is called items and the row is called link. Is my sql syntax right? Also the print.php just prints out the html

Comment: about print.php - your jQuery post seems to not care about return - so it wasting of CPU to produce it

Comment: well what im trying to do is repost the html and if the link has already been visited i was going to attach a css class to it to demonstrate that. So the print.php does that.